# Testing POST Request in REST

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, testing, post

I am using Postman (chrome extension) to test this REST service and I am able to successfully test GET and DELETE: `http://localhost:8080/mt-rest/rest/user/321`, but not POST, even after giving form data.
I get.. The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("rest")
public class TestController {![enter image description here][2]

    @Autowired
    private MultitenantService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserInfo(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return service.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getCustomers() {
        return service.getUsers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<TodoItem> getTransactions(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return getUserInfo(id).getTodoItems();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<TodoItem> addTransaction(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody TodoItem todoItem) {

        User user = getUserInfo(id);
        user.getTodoItems().add(todoItem);

        service.save(user);

        return user.getTodoItems();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/todo/{todoId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public User addTransaction(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Long todoId) {

        User user = getUserInfo(id);

        user.deleteTodo(todoId);

        service.save(user);

        return getUserInfo(id);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In my POST method I changed from @RequestBody to @ModelAttribute and now I am getting

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [net.tajzich.mt.domain.TodoItem] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class net.tajzich.mt.domain.TodoItem, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
```

]

Comment: Not going in too much details, but I think your POST method here `@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/todo"` is defined wrongly. You are not requesting anything, but you are _submitting_ to the webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, I was not setting up the header properly.
**-H "Content-Type: application/json"**

```
$ curl -i -X POST -d '{"version":"1","name":"Himalay","done":"false"} ' http://localhost:8080/mt-rest/rest/user/2/todo -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type:
>   application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 23 Jan 2014
>   22:17:34 GMT

========================================================================